# Html img tag breaks while formatting code

Tags: html, css

Without code formatting

```
<img src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8450/8026519634_f33f3724ea_b.jpg"><img
    src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7218/7209301894_c99d3a33c2_h.jpg"><img
    src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7231/6947093326_df216540ff_b.jpg">
```

Output:
[image: Without Code format]

With code formatting

```
<img src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8450/8026519634_f33f3724ea_b.jpg">
<img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7218/7209301894_c99d3a33c2_h.jpg">
<img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7231/6947093326_df216540ff_b.jpg">
```

Output:
[image: With code formatting]

Why is it behaving like this with just simple code formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because spaces between inline content matter. They stop words running into each other.

```html
<p>no-spaces</p>
<div><img src="//placekitten.com/15/15"><img src="//placekitten.com/15/15"></div>
<p>s p a c e s</p>
<div><img src="//placekitten.com/15/15"> <img src="//placekitten.com/15/15"></div>
```

You can have more control over the layout by making the images, for example, [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) items instead of regular inline boxes.

Comment: Wrapping image in div with `display:flex` solved it. The problem was the space between the contents as said by the @Quentin. thanks.